# HTTP cloud scheduler job fails to trigger cloud run even with oidc service account authentication

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-scheduler

HTTP cloud scheduler job fails to trigger cloud run endpoint. Created a service account and its provided with *cloud scheduler* and *cloud run admin roles*. On cloud run permissions tab the account is given *cloud run invoker permission*. The cloud run endpoint can be triggered on console and returns successfully. The cloud scheduler job is getting created if no authentication is required and when it sends a request cloud run returns 403 HTTP response. Command used is

```
gcloud beta scheduler jobs create http *job_name* --schedule="* * * * *" --uri="https://*cloud-run-app-name-*cno4ptsl2q-ew.a.run.app" --http-method=GET --oidc-service-account-email="*project_id_number*@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com"
```

On Console when this command is run *invalid argument* error occurs. When I do it on console *creating job failed Unknown Error*

Answer (score 0):

**OIDC**

needs the url in the `AUD` param, make sure you have it.

best would be to use `OAUTH`

**OAUTH**

you need only the service account and scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform

Comment: A URL must start with "https://", and host must end with ".googleapis.com" for a job with an OAuth authorization header.
This is given in the docs and this validation check is present on GUI.
The URL I am trying to reach is one of cloud run which is likehttps://job-name-cno4ptsl2q-ew.a.run.app/endpoint. I have to use OIDC itself. can you explain more about the AUD param

Answer (score 0):

When you use OIDC authentication, you must specify "OIDC Audience" in your command if you didn't specify in URI.

Refer [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/scheduler/jobs/create/http#--oidc-token-audience) to get more info about Cloud scheduler's OIDC audience flag.

It seems that your URI didn't include audience value.

Check attached link and retry creation job after add audience flag in your command.

This is my command which successed to create Cloud scheduler job

```
gcloud scheduler jobs create http deax-tweets-collection --schedule='* * * * *' \ --uri='https://job-name-cno4ptsl2q-ew.a.run.app' --http-method='GET' \ --oidc-service-account-email='XXXXX@project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com' \ --oidc-token-audience='https://job-name-cno4ptsl2q-ew.a.run.app'
```

Comment: tried 
`gcloud scheduler jobs create http dax-tweets-collection --schedule="* * * * *" --uri="https://job-name-cno4ptsl2q-ew.a.run.app" --http-method=GET --oidc-service-account-email="project_name@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com" --oidc-token-audience="https://job-name-cno4ptsl2q-ew.a.run.app"`
This still gives the same error
`ERROR: (gcloud.scheduler.jobs.create.http) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Request contains an invalid argument.
`

Comment: Get rid of all quotation marks( " ) except cron syntax, and try again. As far as i know, quotations marks doesn't exist in command.

Comment: The same error even without the quotation marks

Comment: I just checked my scheduler create job command. In my command, All values are enclosed with single quotations( ' ). Maybe --http-method=GET could be cause of problem. Try again with --http-method='GET'

Comment: The service account email you used is Google API service agent account(project-id@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com). That could be a problem. I tried my command below, and successed creation job with my normal service account(XXXX@project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com).

Comment: This is my command which successed to create Cloud scheduler job

`gcloud scheduler jobs create http deax-tweets-collection --schedule='* * * * *' \
--uri='https://job-name-cno4ptsl2q-ew.a.run.app' --http-method='GET' \
--oidc-service-account-email='XXXXX@project-id.iam.gserviceaccount.com' \
--oidc-token-audience='https://job-name-cno4ptsl2q-ew.a.run.app'`